# Can't install Project Prey on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, gtk

When trying to install Project Prey 1.4.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 I get the following error: `(gksu:4076): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0.0`. Prey unfortunately doesn't have a forum to ask for help so I post here. Does anyone know how I can fix this? I've tried everything I can think of. Prey's support (for a free product mind you) only gave me the .deb which I already can get from their website. Here is the full output of the installation: https://gist.github.com/crsleeth/93b01e73690409a88f02

It says it is successful, but isn't. The Prey GUI configuration tool doesn't launch after it is finished like it is supposed to, and even though the Prey package is installed no Prey bash commands are recognized.

Please, any help? I can't install Prey on my laptop or desktop.

Answer (score 0):

This command worked for me:

```
sudo /usr/lib/prey/versions/1.5.0/bin/prey config gui
```

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the repeat attempt to configure prey every time packages are installed/upgraded, edit the file `/var/lib/dpkg/info/prey.postinst` by remarking the following line:

 `74       # env DISPLAY=:0.0 gksu -u $PREY_USER "$PREY_BIN config gui"`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You access path `/usr/lib/prey/current/bin` and `sudo ./prey config gui` to log in prey account.